# SQLalchemy query column by name

Tags: sqlalchemy

I need to select multiple users by various field values like, where `field` is a string of the column name like 'name' or 'email':

```
users = meta.Session.query(User) \
    .filter(User[field].in_(values)) \
    .all()
```

How do I programmatically access a column by its name?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood well, you could use [literal_column](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal_column) or standard [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr), see this example:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, types
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import literal_column

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=False)

Base = declarative_base()
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    login = Column(types.String(50), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(types.String(255))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "User(login=%r, name=%r)" % (self.login, self.name)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # create two users    
    u1 = User(login='someone', name="Some one")
    u2 = User(login='someuser', name="Some User")
    u3 = User(login='user', name="User")
    u4 = User(login='anotheruser', name="Another User")
    session.add(u1)
    session.add(u2)
    session.add(u3)
    session.add(u4)
    session.commit()

    print "using literal_column"
    print session.query(User).filter(literal_column("login").in_(["someuser", "someone"])).all()

    print "using getattr"
    print session.query(User).filter(getattr(User, "login").in_(["someuser", "someone"])).all()
```

output:

```
using literal_column
[User(login=u'someone', name=u'Some one'), User(login=u'someuser', name=u'Some User')]
using getattr
[User(login=u'someone', name=u'Some one'), User(login=u'someuser', name=u'Some User')]
```

If you will use `literal_column`, beware that the argument is inserted into the query without any transformation. **This may expose you to a SQL Injection vulnerability** if you accept values for the text parameter from outside your application.